# Query associated domain object with params gives error: Cannot query property "params" - no such property on class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain objects:
HeadOfHousehold, and Address,

In HeadOfHousehold I have the following relationship:

```
Address currentAddress
Address previousAddress
```

In Address I have:

```
static belongsTo = [headOfHousehold: HeadOfHousehold]
```

I have the following query:

```
def customers = HeadOfHousehold.findAll {
            if(params.lastName){
                lastName =~ params.lastName+ "%"
            }
            if(params.firstName){
                firstName =~ params.firstName + "%"
            }
            if(params.middleName){
                middleName =~ params.middleName + "%"
            }
            if(params.city){
                currentAddress.city =~ params.city+ "%"
            }
            if(params.zipCode){
                currentAddress.zipCode == params.zipCode
            }
            if(params.extendedZipCode){
                currentAddress.extendedZipCode == params.extendedZipCode
            }

        }
```

The problem is  on those final three statements I get the error:

`Cannot query property "params" - no such property on class HeadOfHousehold`

It does not complain about the queries associated with lastName firstName or middleName, just when I go into the address.  I can get around it by saving the params in a string and going that way:

```
String city = params.city + "%"
        String zipCode = params.zipCode
        String extendedZipCode = params.extendedZipCode
        String state = params.state
        def customers = HeadOfHousehold.findAll {
            if(params.lastName){
                lastName =~ params.lastName+ "%"
            }
            if(params.firstName){
                firstName =~ params.firstName + "%"
            }
            if(params.middleName){
                middleName =~ params.middleName + "%"
            }
            if(params.city){
                currentAddress.city =~ city 
            }
            if(params.state){
                currentAddress.state == state
            }
            if(params.zipCode){
                currentAddress.zipCode == zipCode
            }
            if(params.extendedZipCode){
                currentAddress.extendedZipCode == extendedZipCode
            }

        }
```

Why is that necessary?  What am I doing wrong? (using grails version 2.3.8)

Comment: Which version of Grails?

Comment: 2.3.8 I am using GGTS for editing my files, but use seperate console to run etc.. because GGTS isn't great for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to match against the property of an association or of a property, it looks `params` as a property on the parent class. I am not fully sure if this is an expected behavior. I will look into it more.

But you can very well surmount this problem by using the way you did or just use the closure approach (DSL way) compared to `.` operation. For example:

```
if(params.city){
    currentAddress { city =~ params.city+ "%" }
}
if(params.zipCode){
    currentAddress { zipCode == params.zipCode } 
}
if(params.extendedZipCode){
    currentAddress { extendedZipCode == params.extendedZipCode }
}
```

Comment: I like this technique better, cleaner, however can you explain how that works?  I'm fairly new to database manipulation in general and am still getting used to it all.  I've been scouring the grails manual in regards to queries and don't remember seeing anything like this.  If you don't mind I would like it very much if you could explain the syntax, and perhaps provide a link for additional reading?

Comment: Go through [this section](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/single.html#criteria) mainly "Querying Associations", you will get it easily. In your case it is a property which works the same way.